# Exception in thread "main" Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
class Squr
{
  public static void main ()
  { 
   int m =10,n;
   double z = 10.4,p;
   Squr square = new Squr();
   p = (double)square.mysqrt(z);
   n = (int)square.mysqrt(m);
   System.out.println ("square root of 10 : " + n );
   System.out.println ("square root of 10.4 : "+ p );  
  }
    double mysqrt (double y)
   {
     return Math.sqrt(y);
   }
   int mysqrt (int x)
   {
     return (int)Math.sqrt(x);
   }

}
```

This code is compiling but when  we try to execute it it giving   " Exception in thread "main" Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main "

Comment: Pay (close) attention to the error messages and full-type signatures. Happy coding.

Comment: This Community Wiki question lists the possible causes of this common problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `main()` function should be declared like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct method signature for the `main` method in Java is:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Simply add the missing arguments in you method declaration and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

### Try that:

```
public static void main(String [ ] args)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've not defined your main method with the correct signature. It should be:

```
public class Squr
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main() method should be like that

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Comment: Above two suggestion public static void main(String args[]) and public static void main(String[] args) is working well but not third one...

Comment: It should work. It works for me. Here is demo http://ideone.com/OhZvh

Comment: Note that the 3rd option will only compile when using Java 5+ as that is when the varargs (...) notation was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a strong type language. You must declare the method in a given way.
The right way to define the main() method is:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

Comment: There are already 5, nearly identical answers. Can you point out what is new in your answer? Couldn't you comment on one of the other posts? If you agree with another post, vote it up, but don't repeat it, especially not 3 months later. Thank you.