# THE CLASSICAL ---> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>     [Exception in thread “main” Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827060/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main)

```
public class InsertionSort
{
public static void main ( int[] a)
{
    int j;
    for( int p=1 ; p<a.length ; p++)
    {
        int tmp = a[p];
        for( j=p ; j>0 && tmp<a[j-1] ; j--)
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
        }
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}
}
```

And this happens in Terminal. (I'm on a Mac if it matters)
javac InsertionSort.java;java InsertionSort
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Comment: What's "CLASSICAL" about this?

Answer (score 3):

You need a proper main() to make the class runnable. A main method should have an array of string as the only argument, you have an array of ints.

So, to solve it, redeclare it to "public static void main(String[] args)" and do the integer parsing in the method. Neither java nor the OS will do that conversion for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String[] arg)
```

main accepts array of string, not array of int.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM lookt for a `public static void main(String[])` signature, not for a main method that takes an `int[]` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

It will run if you do it like this:

```
public static void main ( String[] args)
{
    int[] a = new int[args.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    int j;
    for( int p=1 ; p<a.length ; p++)
    {
        int tmp = a[p];
        for( j=p ; j>0 && tmp<a[j-1] ; j--)
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
        }
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

A main method, needs a String array, you need an int array, so we'll just convert the one to the other.